# Cant bind <SPC> in evil mode?

Tags: evil

for some reason i cant bind space in evil mode and get an error. all other keys work well. any clue? this is the bind that dosent seem to work

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map "<SPC>" 'hydra-leader/body)`

here is the error i get when launching emacs: 
`Error (use-package): evil :config: Key sequence < S P C > starts with non-prefix key <`

Comment: If you get an error, show the exact error to us.  We're after all not psychics...

Comment: good point ;-) here is the error i get when launching emacs: ```Error (use-package): evil :config: Key sequence < S P C > starts with non-prefix key <```

Comment: Try `"SPC"` instead? I think you're mixing notations (`<space>` vs `SPC`)

Comment: using SPC gives the same error:```Error (use-package): evil :config: Key sequence S P C starts with non-prefix key S```

Comment: Try `(kbd "SPC")` instead, or `[space]` - in any case, look for the right notation ;)

Comment: (or just `" "`)

Comment: this is what i have ```(define-key evil-normal-state-map "SPC" 'hydra-leader/body)``` im petty sure SPC is the correct notation isnt it?

Comment: No, it's not. As I said before, try either `(kbd "SPC")`, `[space]`, or simply `" "` instead. If you read the error, it believes you're trying to map a sequence of 3 keys, the first one being `S`.

Comment: thx! ```(kbd "SPC")`` did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code shows that emacs believes you want to map a sequence of 3 keys (`S` `P` `C`), the first one being `S`, but it can't do that since `S` is already used by itself (i.e. not a prefix key).

You can use either `(kbd "SPC")`, `[space]` or simply `" "` instead. For example:

```
 (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC") 'hydra-leader/body)
```

For the right key syntax, see for example the "How to find key syntax" question at [this Xah tutorial page](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html).

(basically, use `C-h k` with the key or key combination you want, in order to see how the output is formatted).