# How to a create key binding to open a particular file?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, spacemacs, org-capture

How to change the `SPC m c` (`org-capture`) key binding to open the `~/capture.org` file instead?

`F-5` opens file when this is in `.spacemacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda() (interactive)(find-file "~/capture.org")))
```

My failed attempt to bind `SPC m c`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "SPC m c") (lambda() (interactive)(find-file "~/capture.org")))
```

got this error:

```
Key sequence `SPC m c` starts with non-prefix key `SPC`
```

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Comment: Please go into more detail than "did not open file" and describe what exactly happened. Did Emacs display an error in the echo area?

Comment: <f6> was bound to ivy-resume.
Changing the binding to <f5> fixed it, so now file opens.
I updated the question.

Comment: See function `define-prefix-command` and, more generally, [(elisp) Prefix Keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/cant-bind-spc-in-evil-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This binds SPC m c to opening the ~/capture.org file:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "mc" (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/capture.org")))
```

The spacemacs manual explains how spacemacs/set-leader-keys works:
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#binding-keys

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the bookmark feature.

On vanilla emacs, `C-x r m` will bookmark the current file, and `C-x r b` will let you choose from a list of bookmarked files. It's amazingly useful

Comment: Not what the question was asking for, but I found it useful nonetheless. +1