# How to bind a key in Evil Spacemacs when the leader key is comma?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

I have rebound "SPC m c" so it opens a file (from [How to a create keybinding to open a particular file?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33913/how-to-a-create-keybinding-to-open-a-particular-file#comment52456_33913)):

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "mc" (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/capture.org")))
```

And it opens the file as intended, because spacemacs/set-leader-keys is for binding with the leader key SPC.

Now I want to bind the same thing to ", c".
How to bind a key when the leader key is comma?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs on Linux.

**UPDATE_1**

I put this in ~/.spacemacs but then Emacs would say "Spacemacs encountered an error while loading your ~/.spacemacs file.":

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map ",c" (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/capture.org")))
```

I put this in ~/.spacemacs but it had no effect (", c" opened agenda dispatcher as usual):

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map ",c" (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/capture.org"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install evil-leader package and create your own leader apart from SPC.
Or you can use

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd ", m c") 'command)
```

ps: check the quotes, I am not sure about them

Comment: I attempted this with the ",mc" key sequence bound to (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "~/capture.org")).  See the attempt in question's **UPDATE_1**.

Comment: I tried it as well. But it works well for me. Check if you have any other commands for the same key binding

Comment: Default Evil Spacemacs ",c" keybinding is org-capture.
So that could could be a conflict.
Are you using Evil Spacemacs?

Comment: yeah I am using evil spacemacs and I haven't enabled org layer. Check the org layer config and try to override it.

Comment: Where is ""org layer config"?  Google did not find it.

Comment: It's in .emacs.d/layers/+emacs/org folder. Apparently spacemacs use  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode .. to define ",c"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61928/discussion-between-user2867994-and-harindu-dilshan).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have changed the SPC to , already.
`M-m` is the other name for `spacemacs/set-leader-keys`

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-m c") (lambda () (interactive) 
(find-file "~/capture.org")))
```

Comment: "these kinds of questions" what?  Please explain.  I am new to Emacs and the Emacs community and want to use the appropriate forum.